# Does WebDatePicker support highlighting various dates?

Tags: asp.net, infragistics

I'm sorry if this is a "Uhh RTFM" type of question, but I've checked the Infragistics website ([www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/web-date-picker.aspx](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/aspnet/web-date-picker.aspx)) and this control has very little documentation and half the pages don't even load.  I dug around the control with Intellisense but nothing jumped out at me.

I'm wondering if anyone knows if this control supports "highlighting" various dates.  A feature request for our website is to highlight all company holidays on the dropdown calendars, and I'd like to know if this is possible to do without all sorts of hackiness.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Infragistics forum there are explanation how to do this on WebDateChooser which is similar control to the WebDatePicker: [Link to Infragistics forum](http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/45550.aspx)

Comment: Ah, yeah I think that logic can be modified to work.  Thanks!  Though turns out this feature got punted because no one cared enough heh.

Comment: well just post in the forum and someone from the support would suggest a solution